# There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name

Tags: java, struts2

Currently I am working in a Live struts2 project. The project works fine. But sometimes, I get some unexpected behavior.

As an example, I was testing the project, everything was working fine. Suddenly I repeated the same operations and got the following error.

```
Struts Problem Report Struts has detected an unhandled exception: Messages: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name rfq. Stacktraces There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name rfq. - [unknown location] com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189) org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61) org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39) com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58) org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488) org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled. Development mode, or devMode, enables extra debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers. To disable this mode, set: struts.devMode=false in your WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties file.
```

I tested again with the same operations and it worked fine.

I did a research on the problem but the solutions were for frequent errors, but this error appears seldom and unexpectedly.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem and solved?

N.B : I am sorry I could not share project structure for lack of time. Any help will be appriciated.

Following actions are responsible

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>
<!--<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/CommonsFileUploadServlet" />-->
<!--<constant name="struts.multipart.handler" value="jakarta" />-->
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="100000000"/>
<!--<constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="D:/tmp" />-->

<!--<package name="com/deloitte/in/action" extends="struts-default"> -->
<!--<package name="mbe/iproc/action" extends="json-default">-->
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">


    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="SessionCheckInterceptor"
                     class="mbe.iproc.interceptor.SessionCheckInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="testSessionValidationStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="SessionCheckInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor name="MyFile"
                     class="mbe.iproc.interceptor.MyFileInterceptor">


        </interceptor>

        <interceptor-stack name="fileUploadStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="MyFile" />
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
        </interceptor-stack>

    </interceptors>



    <!--<default-interceptor-ref name="loggedInDefaultStack" />-->

    <global-results>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="sessionexpired">/sessionExpiredIntermediate.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping
                exception="org.apache.struts.register.exceptions.SecurityBreachException"
                result="securityerror"/>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
                           result="error"/>
    </global-exception-mappings>




<action name="LOGIN" class="loginAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">POOUST</result>
        <result name="failure">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="firstentry">/change_password.jsp</result>
    </action>


<action name="POOUST" method="poOustList" class="poOustAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="testSessionValidationStack"/>
        <result name="success">/home.jsp</result>
        <result name="superLoginSuccess">/homeAdmin.jsp</result>
        <result name="scmLoginSuccess">/homeScm.jsp</result>
        <result name="qaSuperLoginSuccess">/homeQA.jsp</result>
        <result name="inspLoginSuccess">/homeQA.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/home.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: You can post the struts.xml file?

Comment: tried a lot but struts.xml's indention was wrong and it contains over 500 actions

Comment: please post the code of mapping where you are doing struts.xml
and also provide what actions you are calling

Comment: Do you get the error after you've made some change that would cause your container to reload the application?  Otherwise, the only thing I see is that maybe having devMode=true is causing this.  What version of Struts2 are you currently using?

Comment: This kind of issue happens because of un-mapped action. It is possible that you have written any action somewhere in your struts form and forgot to map that action here in your struts.xml mapping file. So better to look carefully and map all the actions which you are using.